# ConvertView items partially updated

Tags: android, listview, convertview

I have custom ListView in my activity and it uses ConvertView pattern and ViewHolder.
Everything works fine, but sometimes text in items are cuted off.
This is clearly seen on screenshots:

### [image: screenshot]

It looks like it reuse old view and don't update text length.
Here is part of adapter code:

```
if (convertView == null) {
     viewHolder = new ViewHolderItemBool();

     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     if (changeable) {
         convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sensor_bool_e, null, true);
     } else {
         convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sensor_bool, null, true);
     }

     viewHolder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
     viewHolder.txtDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDescript);
     viewHolder.imgState = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);
     convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
} else {
     viewHolder = (ViewHolderItemBool) convertView.getTag();
}
viewHolder.txtName.setText(name);
if (isImportant()) viewHolder.txtName.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
//some code to change description field and picture
return convertView;
```

And here is item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/sensor_bool"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/sensor_background"
    android:longClickable="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/circle_green"
        android:padding="10dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sensor_text_size"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/sensor_name_color"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDescript"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingStart="2dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sensor_desc_size"
            android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_light"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

If I don't use ConverView and inflate layout each time it looks fine.
Have any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: have your declare changeable as static ?

Comment: try `convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sensor_bool_e, parent, false);` instead of `convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sensor_bool_e, null, true);`

Comment: @RanjitPati no, but the problem still here even if I remove this part of code and use only one layout

Comment: @shayanpourvatan it crashes with exception UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView

Comment: I've changed android:layout_width="fill_parent" in txtName to android:layout_width="wrap_content", now text displayed fine. But normal/bold text still changes time to time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it! It was just few stupid errors.

First:
I changed

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

in txtName to

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

This solves problem with text width. I do not understand why it did not work before?

And second:

```
if (isImportant()) viewHolder.txtName.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
```

to

```
if (isImportant()) {
    viewHolder.txtName.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
} else {
    viewHolder.txtName.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
}
```

This solves the problem with bold text. (The problem is don't described in question but seen on screens.)

Thanx to all for help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to owerride some methods of BaseAdapter to show different listview items:

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (changeable) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've just tryed this, android:layout_width="wrap_content" is enough. But why normal/bold text is not updated?

Comment: I've override them, without that it don't work at all. Actually I have 5 view types, I post here only part of code because it is pretty long.